# Horizontal Navigation Menu using image sprite

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I have made a website but the problem is I am not able to fix the navigation menu for it. I have an image sprite with 6 menu items.
But on hovering over it , I don't see the drop down menu coming. 
I have tried so many different things. 
I am frustrated and ready to discard the entire website.

Here is the code

### HTML part:

http://www.codesend.com/view/3256019e6d25498ae6327284a187b1f6/

### CSS part:

http://www.codesend.com/view/77b1a413d602ef76dbe47ae2478c7ecf/

Please help . 
Not able to figure out what the problem is. 
In case nothing works. I want to give away the sprite but create equal width and space menu. Please help very urgent and critical

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have better luck getting help with your code in a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Just look on this example, please, jsfiddle.net/qt9Uj/. 
There is simple html and css that, I hope, help you to solve your problem.